# Jquery code won't run loaded from WP, but run from console

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a value and pass it to a hidden input in order to send form data via $_POST. I have a dropdown button and the following code in order to update the value:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var espSeleccionada = $('button[data-id="select-especialidad"]');
    espSeleccionada.on("click", function() {
        // if changed to, for example, the last option, then
        // $(this).find('option:selected').text() == D
        // $(this).val() == 4
        // get whatever value you want into a variable
        var x = $(this).text();
        // and update the hidden input's value
        $('#boton-prueba').text(x);
    });

});
```

The code is supposed to pass the value from one button to another, as shown in [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t9mvoxj5/) the example, but, when I load the code from WordPress nothing happens. Instead, when I write it on the console it works fine. There are no JS errors in console.

Please note that I'm using .text() to test if the code works, but it would have .val() before going live.

This is the button HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="select-especialidad" title="Hacienda" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Hacienda</span></button>
```

[Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t9mvoxj5/) is an example.

**EDIT TO CLARIFY HOW I AM ADDING THE CODE TO IN WORDPRESS:**

I add the script via functions.php. This is my code:

```
function loading_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'buscopreparador-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_deregister_style( 'buscopreparador-style' );

    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'vertical-tabs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.vertical-tabs.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-select-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,600italic,400italic,700,700italic');

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', false, false, TRUE );
        wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', false, false, TRUE );
        wp_register_script('bootstrap-tabcollapse', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap-tabcollapse.js', false, false, TRUE );
        wp_register_script('bootstrap-select', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js', false, false, TRUE );
        wp_register_script('theme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), false, TRUE );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-tabcollapse' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-select' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-js' );
    }

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loading_my_scripts' );
```

The code is in **theme.js** file which looks like this:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var num_cols = 3,
    container = $('#menu-preparadores-de-oposiciones-en'),
    listItem = 'li',
    listClass = 'sub-list';
    container.each(function() {
        var items_per_col = new Array(),
        items = $(this).find(listItem),
        min_items_per_col = Math.floor(items.length / num_cols),
        difference = items.length - (min_items_per_col * num_cols);
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            if (i < difference) {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col + 1;
            } else {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            $(this).append($('<ul ></ul>').addClass(listClass));
            for (var j = 0; j < items_per_col[i]; j++) {
                var pointer = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    pointer += items_per_col[k];
                }
                $(this).find('.' + listClass).last().append(items[j + pointer]);
            }
        }
    });

    if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-64")) {
      $('.tab-content').addClass('col-sm-9');
      $('#custom-tabs-0').tabCollapse();
    } 

} ) ( jQuery );

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var espSeleccionada = $('button[data-id="select-especialidad"]');
    espSeleccionada.on("click", function() {
        // if changed to, for example, the last option, then
        // $(this).find('option:selected').text() == D
        // $(this).val() == 4
        // get whatever value you want into a variable
        var x = $(this).html();
        // and update the hidden input's value
        $('#boton-prueba').html(x);
    });

}); 

( function() {
    var is_webkit = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'webkit' ) > -1,
        is_opera  = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'opera' )  > -1,
        is_ie     = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'msie' )   > -1;

    if ( ( is_webkit || is_opera || is_ie ) && document.getElementById && window.addEventListener ) {
        window.addEventListener( 'hashchange', function() {
            var id = location.hash.substring( 1 ),
                element;

            if ( ! ( /^[A-z0-9_-]+$/.test( id ) ) ) {
                return;
            }

            element = document.getElementById( id );

            if ( element ) {
                if ( ! ( /^(?:a|select|input|button|textarea)$/i.test( element.tagName ) ) ) {
                    element.tabIndex = -1;
                }

                element.focus();
            }
        }, false );
    }
})();
```

Comment: please define "won't run". Have you checked of JS errors?

Comment: The code is supposed to pass the value from one button to another, as shown the linked example, but, when I load the code from WordPress nothing happens. Instead, when I write it on the console it works fine. I've checked for JS errors and I receive the following message related with the customizer: Uncaught TypeError: wp.customize is not a function.

Comment: how is your code related to the customizer?

Comment: Not related at all

Comment: anyway, you problem is probably the error which makes other things not to execute at all due to bailing out on the exception

Comment: if it is not related why do you call `wp.customize`

Comment: I guess your problem starts when you include JS that should be there only for the customizer and it gives you errors in other context

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood. The w.customize is related with the customizer, but not with my issue, or the code that I am trying to implement

Comment: Hello again @MarkKaplun, I've solved the wp.customize problem, I was loading it in the wrong file/moment. Now I don't have any JS error, but again, the script doesn't load.

Comment: tried renaming the register script name with something else (i.e not theme-js)? Is the js file loaded (you can find out in the browser inspector)?

Comment: Hello @juz, the file is loaded because this part of code (`if ($("body").hasClass("page-id-64")) {
      $('.tab-content').addClass('col-sm-9');
      $('#custom-tabs-0').tabCollapse();
    } `)is working fine and I can find it with the inspector.

Comment: while you have the inspector, you can add breakpoints in both the document ready and the click event.. does it hit any breakpoints?

Comment: @juz I don't understand. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: in the inspector you have multiple tabs.. there should be a tab called source.. in there it allows you find loaded javascript files and to add breakpoints in source to debug whether a line is run/hit..  the tab could be named differently depending on which browser you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the code is fine, the problem is that the target `button[data-id="select-especialidad"]` is being used by bootstrap-select and even if the script load before my code, it takes a few seconds or less to process the information.

So the code should be wrapped after a function that checks that the event has been loaded. This is the final code:

```
$('#select-especialidad').on('loaded.bs.select', function (e) {
    var y = $(this).val();
    $('#select-especialidad-hidden').val(y);

    var espSeleccionada = $('button[data-id="select-especialidad"] > span.filter-option.pull-left');
        espSeleccionada.on("click", function() {
            var x = $(this).text();
            $('#select-especialidad-hidden').val(x);
        });
});
```

loaded.bs.select here more info on the [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events) events.